# How do I update my logic method in Scenekit

Tags: ios, scenekit

I've setup one of my objects to adopt the "SCNSceneRendererDelegate" protocol and I've implemented the renderAtTime: method:

```
- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer updateAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time
{
....
}
```

Now, when I touch the screen and pan my view, the method gets called. That's fine, but it doesn't get called when the view is stationary. What I'm actually looking for is a run-loop - I want to update the position of my objects programmatically, which will then update the "position" vector in the node and hence a new frame will be drawn...

Does Scenekit provide a runloop of sorts, or should I use the GLKit runloop somehow? Or should I use DisplayLink.  There's gotta be a way of using SceneKit to do this without having to employ these other methods.   Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the SCNView to redraw continuously:

```
scnView.playing = YES;
```

Comment: Yeah, this works!  Reading the apple docs they mention that 'playing' is used to playback animations.  Since I didn't have any animations attached to the  scene, I thought it doesn't apply -- well it does.  Also, DisplayLink works as well.